# SCNBox make the front side rotated to the camera in ARKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, scnnode

I have a simple ARKit app. When the user touches the screen

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let result = sceneView.hitTest(touch.location(in: sceneView), types: [ARHitTestResult.ResultType.featurePoint])
    guard let hitResult = result.last else { return }
    let hitTrasform = SCNMatrix4(hitResult.worldTransform)
    let hitVector = SCNVector3Make(hitTrasform.m41, hitTrasform.m42, hitTrasform.m43)

    createBox(position: hitVector)
}
```

I add a cube

```
func createBox(position: SCNVector3) {
    let box = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 1)
    box.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.black

    let sides = [
        UIColor.red,          // Front
        UIColor.black,        // Right
        UIColor.black,        // Back
        UIColor.black,        // Left
        UIColor.black,        // Top
        UIColor.black         // Bottom
    ]

    let materials = sides.map { (side) -> SCNMaterial in
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = side
        material.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true
        return material
    }

    box.materials = materials

    let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
    boxNode.position = position
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
}
```

When I add it for the first time, I see the front side and a bit of the right side. if I go around the cube on the other side and add another cube, I see the back side of the cube. So, can I do it so that the user sees only the front side whatever how the user goes around.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SCNBillboardConstraint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnbillboardconstraint) to make a given node face the camera.  Just add `boxNode.constraints = [SCNBillboardConstraint()]` before adding it to the `rootNode`.

Comment: This is the right answer, but as an alternative, you can set the .orientation property of a node to the .orientation of the pointOfView of the SCNView (the active camera) in the render delegate.